# Did my hard drive fail or is it something else?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

Last night while I was watched a movie on my laptop the external monitor just went blank and the built-in display froze. Weird I thought, so I restarted it only to be greeted with this heart-breaking message. "No Operating System Found". After a few panicked restarts I accepted the fact that my hard drive might be done :(.

Being the resourceful technie that I am, I whipped out Ubuntu Live on my old Flash Drive and was up and running before day break. I cannot access the hard drive through Ubuntu (which I expected) but I also **cannot access my DVD drive either**! This got me thinking that it might not be the hard drive and some other component that they hdd and the dvd uses. Hopefully this is the case.

***Which component is the most likely culprit? What tools can I use from Ubuntu Live on my USB flash drive to find out?***

I'm in a bad place without my hdd, thanks in advance for any assistance provided!

P.S. My laptop makes a weird noise when I try to access or eject my DVD within the slot. Also my HDD makes a weird noise sometimes. Not sure how to describe it.

System Specs:

**Dell 1558**

Comment: This is strange. That message is usually presented when there is a drive detected, but either inactive or does not have a MBR. Do you have two ROM drives? If so, it may be your motherboard. Check whether your DVD drive and HDD plug into adjacent SATA ports on the board. Unfortunately, no software can detect this sort of problem.

Comment: Most likely? The hard drive since it is making strange sounds. Pull the drive from the PC and connect it to another PC using a hard driver to USB adapter, see if you can see any data on the drive, if you can, back up your files, if you cannot most likely the drive has failed.

Comment: Ok, my hdd literally just appeared while in Ubuntu. I can now browse and see all my files perfectly. I'm running SMART data self-tests now to see if it can detect or fix the problem. I'll try and boot from it after the tests are complete.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely? The hard drive since it is making strange sounds. Pull the drive from the PC and connect it to another PC using a [hard driver to USB adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812119152), see if you can see any data on the drive, if you can, back up your files, if you cannot see files most likely the drive has failed